# Join two tables in MSSQL and only return rows with a certain value in a field

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, join, odbc

I have two tables that I am trying to join with a column called "job_id". The first table, "Commitments", contains information about project details, the second table, called "Jobs" contains details about the project managers assigned to a job.

I want to join the two together and return all the rows from "Commitments" that correspond to their project manager (Commitments.Project_Manager).

So, a project manager is assigned multiple projects (contained in jobs), and each project has multiple details about it (in Commitments), so going up the chain, my query should return all the rows going up the chain in Commitments that are associated with a project manager in Jobs.

This is my current query, but it is simply returning all of the results from Commitments:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Commitments 
LEFT JOIN Jobs 
ON Commitments.job_id=Jobs.job_id 
AND Jobs.Project_Manager LIKE :projectmanager"
```

This is being done in PHP/MSSQL with an ODBC connection between the two.

Sorry if this is something really simple, I'm terrible with SQL queries. Thanks!

Comment: Either switch to Jobs left join Commitments, or do a regular inner join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Project_Manager even without commitments:

```
SELECT *
FROM Jobs LEFT JOIN Commitments 
ON Commitments.job_id=Jobs.job_id 
WHERE Jobs.Project_Manager LIKE :projectmanager
```

or if you only want Project_Manager with commitments:

```
SELECT *
FROM Jobs inner JOIN Commitments 
ON Commitments.job_id=Jobs.job_id 
WHERE Jobs.Project_Manager LIKE :projectmanager
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM
Jobs j INNER JOIN Commitments c on j.job_id = c.job_id
WHERE j.project_manager LIKE :projectmanager
```

Comment: Why do select c.*? (Will return null-filled rows when no Commitments match.)